# Cannot run any Java application after latest Java 2012-003 Lion Macosx Update

Tags: java, eclipse, osx-lion

I am in trouble deep, since after the the upgrade I cannot run any Java Application.
In particular some of the most known Java IDE: Eclipse Indigo or IntelliJ 10.

I am trying to interpret the error details, but there's a lot of things and I don't know how to get trough. By running Eclipse from console I get this:

> Invalid memory access of location 0x30469bfa8 rip=0x1040dd43b
>   Segmentation fault: 11

and even when I am able to start, I cannot do anything, all the Eclipse panes show errors, mostly null pointer ones.

Has anyone encountered this ? I have played a bit with the Java preference pane with no success at all.

Update:
After a shutdown (not a restart) everything started working again, but few minutes later same problem again on all Java IDE.

Seems that Apple has solved the correct .dmg download, so I downloaded the update and installed manually, but things are still not working.

By the way, are there any other way to downgrade to latest 002 ?

[EDIT at 27/08/2012]

This problem has gone apparently by itself, I didn't do anything in particular other than following all the upgrade seed by Apple for Lion, all the suggestions pointed out in comments didn't solve the issue. Don't know the policy of 'Superuser' web site, but as I cannot replicate or state a proper way of solving the problem, if you want this question could be closed, or deleted.

Comment: Did you try to manual download and reinstall the update?

Comment: uhm...no should I ? Did you get a similar problem ?

Comment: Luckily no, I've just did the update, but I would give it a try.

Comment: This is the link: http://support.apple.com/downloads/DL1515/en_US/JavaForOSX.dmg but maybe the localization is not the one you want.

Comment: And if you had the Flashback trojan? Check [this](https://www.f-secure.com/v-descs/trojan-downloader_osx_flashback_i.shtml) out.

Comment: nothing to do...manually updated and still got this problem

Comment: Probably not related, but did you try to clean the Java caches (~/Library/Caches/Java)? It has worked for me for some Java troubles.

Comment: Just FYI in case it's not a typo: It's August ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Java Preferences - Enable applet plug-in and Web Start applications.